# Single php array to html table

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

The idea is to print an html table from this array:

```
$arr = ['1','2','3','4,'5,'6','7','8','9'];
```

I expect my table to be something like:

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

I tried a lot but I couldn't find an idea to do this.

My idea was to break each three element but I need something smarter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array-chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) like this:

```
$arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];

echo "<table>";
foreach(array_chunk($arr, 3) as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";   
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];

$from=0; //index from of arr
$number=3; //number cell per row
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row=array_slice($arr,$from,$number)){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";   
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $from+=$number;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
print "<table>\n";
foreach(array_chunk($arr, 3) as $row) {
        print "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $col) {
                print "<td>";
                print $col;
                print "</td>";
        }   
        print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>";
?>
```